# Controlling HTML from WebParts in Microsoft Dynamics AX

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, axapta

I have a website running in Microsoft SharePoint which uses menus and other data from Dynamics AX 4.0. I have a weblet in the website where I fetch a menu from Dynamics AX, which uses the WebMenuWebLet and WebVertMenuHTML classes to generate the HTML to be displayed on the page. I have now tried to strip everything from the weblet to reconstruct it from scratch to fit my design, but it still outputs some data.

I read on [this page](http://weblogs.asp.net/bsimser/archive/2006/01/25/436428.aspx) that the WebParts in Dynamics AX always output some boilerplate HTML, and what I am getting is indeed the HTML snippet in this blog. However, I also get more HTML code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/_layouts/ep/stylesheets/AXEP.css">
```

This stylesheet has a lot of definitions, some conflicting with my own, so I'd like to get rid of the link to it. Deleting the contents of AXEP.css is not an option, as I am reconstructing a live website where the old part is still using that data, and I have to work on the same Dynamics AX server as is being used for the live site.

I can imagine it being difficult to remove the <table> tag mentioned in the blog I linked to, but I am hoping that there is some way for me to remove the link to the stylesheet. I have searched through all the class definitions in Dynamics AX, but found nothing that helped me, so is there any other place I should look?

I'm sorry if the information is vague, I'm kinda lost when it comes to those Microsoft solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been a long time since a asked and I'd like to close the question, so here is what I did:

I noticed that the `<link>` tag that points to the extra CSS is only inserted in the first WebPart on the page. Instead of getting rid of it I added an extra WebPart to the top of the page that did nothing but output this boilerplate `<link>` tag (along with some `<script>` tags that I didn't want either) and wrapped it inside an HTML comment: `<!-- -->`. It is still inserted into the page now, but the browser ignores it so the CSS doesn't affect the layout of the page.

It is an ugly hack, but it was the best I could come up with at the time.

Answer (score 0):

Look in Sharepoint, since AX does not seem to emit this code.

You should most likely create [a new Enterprise Portal style sheet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa872388.aspx) and then create [a new Sharepoint theme](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa867986.aspx).